# Angular : template changing depending on javascript value

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular, ng-switch

I am building an angular app, with templates changing depending on  with ngscope as seen on the samples  below.

```
<label class="btn btn-default">
  <input id="cacher" value="settings" type="radio" data-ng-model="user.status">Settings
</input>
</label>
```

and here i'm calling my html template userPageSettings

```
<div id="wrapper" ng-switch="user.status">
    <div ng-switch-when="settings">
        <user-page-settings></user-page-settings>
      </div>
</div>
```

Trouble is, i'm trying to get access to the templates (and the correct route) through a dropdown in the navbar, which is supposed to do exactly the same thing as my normal menu. But if i simply call the templates from my navbar they will be shown on the current page, therefore at the incorrect route.

In my navbar code i'm doing the following, which is bringing me back to the correct route, but showing me my default template (aka home, not shown here, but called through the same method and has the number 6)

```
<li role="menuitem"><a href="/user/:username/1">Settings</a></li>
```

The number "1" (and the others using 2,3 etc) are hashed in my javascript and put into a variable. I would like to make my templates appear depending on those numbers.

Any ideas how ?? 
:) Thank you !!

Comment: it's not clear what your issue is.  first, your question title suggests some kind of issue with `ng-scope` (whatever that is), but it appears to be related to routing;  In order to help diagnose routing issues, it is generally necessary to see the routing code you are trying to reach.

Comment: Ok i wasn't clear so i edited my question... Actually i'm trying to change the user.status value so that my templates would be triggered through javascript...

Comment: ok, so where are you changing the values?  where is the vaule `settings` in your URL path?  what does "The number "1" (and the others using 2,3 etc) are hashed in my javascript and put into a variable" mean?

Comment: the value settings is just put inside of user.status, which then toggles my ng-switch-whens, which are calling my templates.
For the 1,2,3 ... values, i'm simply putting them in the URL because i'm hoping to get access to those same templates using those values, which i'm getting back through my javascript.
I hope i'm clear enough :)

Comment: what you are describing sounds like it should work *in theory*, but you have provided almost no code here that will allow anyone to reproduce your conditions and troubleshoot your issue.  it's not clear where your `user.status` is being set, where your `settings` variable is assigned it's value, or even if you have a single or multiple controllers.

Comment: Ok thank you, i'll try to do a jsfiddle, but i have so many file dependencies here it won't be easy !

Comment: "bringing me back to the correct route, but showing me my default template"  Have you done anything with `$routeProvider` or `ui-router` to define the routes you need?